# JS - number circular reference

Tags: javascript, regex, math

I have a variable (number) that can span from `-180` to `180`.

Is there a way I can create a circular reference so that when the variable is `180 || -180`
 it will be equidistant from `90` and `-90`?

---

My code is quite complicated now, and I haven't set a pen yet;
 but basically I'm rotating a cube on Y axis and if back of the cube is set to rotateY(180deg) for it to reach the  left-side (that's set on rotateY(-90deg)) it will pass through right-side (that's set on rotateY(90deg)) , front-side (that's set on rotateY(0deg))....

And since it needs to work both ways around I can't set it neither to -180;

---

**EDIT 1**

[I posted a pen](http://codepen.io/maio/pen/VYmzdZ); hopefully looking at the example you can understand what I mean;

Comment: Add some of the code you've tried yourself

Comment: What do you mean? Only `0` is equidistant from `90` and `-90`.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "circular reference", clearly you don't mean one piece of code indirectly referencing itself (the normal meaning).

Comment: The OP appears to be talking about numbers in the context of degrees of a circle. Ex. the point of the circle at 180 degrees is equidistant between the 90 angle and the -90 angle.

Comment: @Richard I meant circular reference from a math point of view but maybe it's not the correct definition ..

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're specifically working with angles on a circle, in degrees. You could write a `distance` function which calculates the shortest angle between two angles, whether clockwise or counterclockwise. Then you can use it to confirm whether one angle is equidistant to two other angles.

```
function distance(a,b){
    var diff = Math.abs(b - a) % 360;
    if (diff > 180){diff = 360 - diff;}
    return diff;
}

distance(359,0);                            #result: 1
distance(-180,180);                         #result: 0
distance(90, -180) == distance(-90, -180);  #result: true
distance(90, 180) == distance(-90, 180);    #result: true
```

Comment: since the browser is calculating which is the shortest angle maybe the best solution is creating a function which changes the origin degree right before transformation (depending on direction)